# how to interact with the contract with more complex arguments(sort of a string of struct)

Tags: contract-development

I want develop a contract that can be interacted from outside with a considerably complex argument(like a string of struct), but the Ethereum seems that the contracts can only be communicated with functions using simple arguments like type uint, string, bytes, how can I manage it?
I mean if I want to develop a function with arguments of a string of struct of unspecified length, how can I manage it?

Answer (score 5):

Currently Solidity does not allow you to pass complex types as function arguments into or out of a smart contract. So currently you neither do

`function setMyStruct (myStruct ms) {
...
}`

nor can you do

`function getMyStruct constant returns (myStruct ms) {
...
}`

On work-around is to pass the elements of the struct one by one into the setter and return them one by one from the getter as in

```
contract testStruct {
    struct myStr {
        int a;
        string b;
    }
    myStr storedStr;

    function setMyStr(int a, string b) {
        storedStr.a = a;
        storedStr.b = b;
    }

    function getMyStr() constant returns (int a, string b) {
        a = storedStr.a;
        b = storedStr.b;
    }
}
```

Check also the following links to follow up on that:

- https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/40
- https://www.pivotaltracker.com/n/projects/1189488/stories/91594340
- [Is it impossible to use an array of strings as the argument to solidity function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/is-it-impossible-to-use-an-array-of-strings-as-the-argument-to-solidity-function)