# How can I initalise a contract with an array?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

Is there any way I can give a list of values (array or mapping) to the constructor of a contract?

In the style of the following code:

```
contract myContract {

    string[] public myArray;

    function myContract(string[] myArray) {
        myArray = myArray;
    }
}
```

I currently get the message from the online compiler:

> Error: Internal type is not allowed for public or external functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works if you change to int,address (which doesn't have a dynamic size as the string)or bytesX (fixed byte array)

```
  string[] public myArray;

  function   myContract (int[] myArray)  {

  }
```

so to understand why there is 2 answers :

1-in the [doc](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#basic-features-for-arrays) :

> generic arrays of fixed and dynamic size are supported in calldata and
>   storage with the following features: Index access, copying (from
>   calldata to storage, inside storage, both including implicit type
>   conversion), enlarging and shrinking and deleting. **Not supported are
>   memory-based arrays (i.e. usage in non-external functions or local
>   variables)**

2-

> Solidity doesn't have a built-in way yet to deserialize string arrays.
>   It can cheat when the contract is passing an array it created itself
>   to itself, which is why it works with private functions. But if you
>   want to take string arrays from the outside, you're going to have to
>   handle the serialization and deserialization from a string (or bytes)
>   yourself. (E.g., concatenating fixed-length items, or using null
>   characters as separators, or using commas, etc.)

source: [Is it impossible to use an array of strings as the argument to solidity function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/is-it-impossible-to-use-an-array-of-strings-as-the-argument-to-solidity-function)

Comment: That makes sense, I assume this applies to arrays of addresses also?

Comment: No address doesn't have a dynamic size like strings or bytes