# Does Solidity support passing an array of strings to a contract's constructor yet?

Tags: contract-deployment, arrays, string, constructor

I am going through a tutorial from 2017 that says it was updated in January of 2018.  It says that currently you can not pass an array of strings directly to the constructor of a contract and that you have to use an array of something like byte32.  Is that still the case?

If you can use an array of strings now and you have a link to an example page, then please share it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can actually use an array of byte32 as an argument to a solidity function as with this constructor function:

```
constructor(bytes32[] memory proposalNames) public {
    chairperson = msg.sender;
    voters[chairperson].weight = 1;

    // For each of the provided proposal names,
    // create a new proposal object and add it
    // to the end of the array.
    for (uint i = 0; i < proposalNames.length; i++) {
        // `Proposal({...})` creates a temporary
        // Proposal object and `proposals.push(...)`
        // appends it to the end of `proposals`.
        proposals.push(Proposal({
            name: proposalNames[i],
            voteCount: 0
        }));
    }
}
```

And this is how you can pass it using web3:

```
let args = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
ballot = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({ 
        data: bytecode, 
        arguments: [args.map((arg) => web3.utils.asciiToHex(arg))]
    })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '6000000' });
```

The point is convert the string array to byte32 array (the hex representation), and just pass it along. The only thing I did to get the hex representation is this :

```
args.map((arg) => web3.utils.asciiToHex(arg))
```

If you have a byte32 return type in a solidity function, you can likewise use one of web3's utility function (web3.utils.bytesToHex('0xf2323de')) to convert it to a string value.

Comment: the constructor code is from the solidity docs: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/solidity-by-example.html

Comment: Thanks.  Have you had any problems with heavy gas usage with functions that accept an array of bytes 32 or "stack too deep" errors?

Comment: I had no problem with gas usage. For the above example I used 6000000 Wei for a gas, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

2022 here, yes it does now. Open this in Remix and use something like ["str1", "str2"] to deploy:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract Strings  {  
    string[] public stringParam;
   
    constructor(string[] memory _stringParam) {
        stringParam = _stringParam;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you cannot use an array of strings or bytes32. Question was already answered [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/is-it-impossible-to-use-an-array-of-strings-as-the-argument-to-solidity-function) ;).