# Where are strings stored in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, storage, string, memory

I wonder where strings are stored in Solidity?

Especially, where are string literals, function arguments, and variables stored?

I recall, I've read that strings cannot be saved to memory, but is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings can be stored in both Storage and Memory - it depends on the type of variable / usage - here's an example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract StorageTest {

    string string1; // string1 is storage

    function func1(string param1) public pure { // param1 is memory
        string memory string2 = "foo";  // string2 is memory in this instance
    }
}
```

There's a great section [in the Solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html?highlight=storage)

And also [a great answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/what-does-the-keyword-memory-do-exactly) from @eth about memory in Ethereum