# How to set a sender address when deploying a contract with Truffle?

Tags: truffle, addresses

I don't seem to find the answer to what looks like a really basic question. How does one specify a sender address when deploying a new contract using Truffle ?

My contract is owned. So most of my functions can only be called by the address that created the contract. Here is a simple contract's code to highlight the issue :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Test {
    address owner;

    modifier restricted() {
        if (msg.sender == owner) _;
    }

    // Constructor
    function Test(){
    owner = msg.sender;
    }

    // Functions reserved to the owner
    function remove() restricted {
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }

    function getOwner() returns (address owner){
        return owner;
    }
}
```

Here are the tests :

```
var assert = require('assert');
var Test = artifacts.require('./Test.sol');

contract('Test', function(accounts){

        it('should test that the Test contract can be deployed', function(done){
            Test.new().then(function(instance){
                assert.ok(instance.address);
            }).then(done);
        });

        it('should test that the Test contract is deployed by the correct address (default)', function(done){
            Test.new().then(function(instance){
                var test = instance;
                test.getOwner.call().then(function(owner){
                    assert.equal(owner, accounts[0], 'Test owned by the wrong address');
                }).then(done);
            });
        });

        it('should test that the Test contract is deployed by the correct address (using from)', function(done){
            Test.new({from: accounts[0]}).then(function(instance){
                var test = instance;
                test.getOwner.call().then(function(owner){
                    assert.equal(owner, accounts[0], 'Test owned by the wrong address');
                }).then(done);
            });
        });
```

Running this, gives me the following result :

```
Contract: Test
✓ should test that the Test contract can be deployed (39ms)
1) should test that the Test contract is deployed by the correct address (default)
> No events were emitted
2) should test that the Test contract is deployed by the correct address (set)
> No events were emitted


1 passing (198ms)
2 failing

1) Contract: Test should test that the Test contract is deployed by the correct address (default):

  Uncaught AssertionError: Test owned by the wrong address
    actual : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    expected : 0xe75bca9dadb23579e105d3a470e9ba0050ad60ce
  + expected - actual

  -0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  +0xe75bca9dadb23579e105d3a470e9ba0050ad60ce

  at test/testTest.js:16:28
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)

2) Contract: Test should test that the Test contract is deployed by the correct address (set):

  Uncaught AssertionError: Test owned by the wrong address
    actual : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    expected : 0xe75bca9dadb23579e105d3a470e9ba0050ad60ce
  + expected - actual

  -0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  +0xe75bca9dadb23579e105d3a470e9ba0050ad60ce

  at test/testTest.js:25:28
  at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

So how can I specify an address ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is actually with the declaration of `getOwner()` in your contract.

`returns (address owner)` works like `return owner` but it expects you to set owner in function's body. Otherwise `owner` is set to zero.
Read more in [Solidity FAQ: Output parameters](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html#output-parameters)

```
function getOwner() returns (address owner) {
    return owner;
}
```

In your example `returns` named argument clashes with contracts state variable `owner`. So, you are actually creating local variable `owner` with zero value and returning it.

Possible solution is to drop `owner` from `returns`:

```
function getOwner() returns (address) {
    return owner;
}
```

---

Btw, I think this is quite counterintuitive and compiler should throw a warning at least.

Comment: Thank you, that was indeed the cause. I'm therefore happy to answer my own question. `Test.new({from: accounts[0]})` does deploy a new Test contract from the `account[0]` address !